# How to change control point of svg path exactly according to draggable helper

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-ui-draggable, bezier

I have an html5 svg path tag as in the Image 1 below.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Now I want to reshape the SVG PATH with the help of draggable helpers (appearing as small circle in the images above). I am able to do it properly with start and end helper. but I am not able to it with mid helper. Whenever I try doing it with the help of mid helper then the mid helper starts going away from the curve as in the Image 2. I want to avoid this and keep the curve always passing through the mid helper as in the Image 1. Here is the d attribute for svg path tag for the curve appearing in the above images:

```
M 237 359 q 536 -54 208 -267
```

I want to use only `q` command with `M` in the same pattern as above because both the start and end markers of svg path elements auto rotate properly only with `Q` and `q` commmands. So I dont want to loose that behaviour. Only thing I want to know here is the logic for calculating the `d` attribute in such a way so that whenever the mid helper is dragged then the curve always pass through the mid helper only like in Image 1 and the start/end points stays at same position. I am using Jquery-UI draggable in order to drag the helpers.

Comment: Check this out: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/quadratic-curve.html

Comment: This is what is already happening in my code. My code is already working exactly like the example you provided. When you drag start/end points then the start/end points stays on the curve. But when you drag mid point then the mid point is not staying on the curve at all. it starts going away from the curve. Which I don't want. I want the mid point to stay on the curve always when it is dragged.

Comment: are these helpers supposed to be "anywhere" or only at the midpoint as @feng described? If you need arbitrary placement, then you will want to read https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#moulding (and the preceding section) on how to do that. If you just need the midpoint, then feng's answer's got you covered. (the computation is not for the true projection, but for quadratic curves it's mostly close enough)

Comment: Yeah these are suppsed to be anywhere. User can drag those helpers anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Q/q command in svg path describes a quadratic Bezier curve where the 2nd control point (i.e., the first two coordinate values of the q command) will always not on the curve.  So, you will have to compute a quadratic Bezier curve interpolating the 3 points you have as below:

1) Assume the 3 points you have are A, B and C where A is the start point, B is the mid-point and C is the end point.

2) Compute t = |AB|/(|AB|+|BC|) where |AB| is the distance between point A and B, and |BC| is the distance between point B and C.

3) Compute the middle control point of the quadratic Bezier curve as

> P1= (B - A(1-t)^2 - C*t^2)/(2*t*(1-t))

Then, you can draw this quadratic Bezier curve using svg path command as

d="M Ax Ay Q P1x P1y Cx Cy"

where Ax, At, P1x, P1y, Cx, Cy are the x, y components of points A, P1 and C. Here, Q command (instead of q) is used so that we can use the point coordinates directly.

Comment: I still didn't get how I will calculate P1. Because A, B and C are points. How can I directly use them in my programmatic expression? Can you please write a line of code in any programming language to represent the formula to calculate P1. I want P1 as an array so that at 0 index I have P1x and at 1 index I have P1y.

Comment: @OP: If you represent a 2d point as an array of 2 elements, then the formula is simply a shorthand for P1[i] = (B[i] - A[i]*(1-t)^2-C[I]*t^2)/(2*t*(1-t)) where i = 0, 1.